# Which function is differentiable on $[a,b]$ but doesn't reach an extreme on $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, mean-value-theorem

I think this is an old question but I can't find any evidence. When I learn about Flett's theorem and Darboux's theorem, we consider it to have an extrema on $(a,b)$ and on two boundaries. But in case it does not reach the extreme at $(a,b)$, it must reach the boundary. As far as I know, when a function is differentiable on $[a,b]$, its graph must always be 'smooth', meaning no sharp corners. Obviously then the peak of the smooth line must be the extreme value. Does this mean that function $f$ is an increasing function?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're wondering if a differentiable function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ with no extrema on $(a,b)$ must be increasing/decreasing, right?

Comment: @AlannRosas That's right

Comment: The title doesn't make sense then. Any function which is differentiable on $[a,b]$ reaches an extremum on $[a,b]$.

Comment: @zkutch careful, $\sin$ has extrema at $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$.

Comment: Consider $\sin$, for example on $[0, 2\pi]$, it is differentiable, but is not increasing/decreasing on all segment. Exists more interesting examples: there is function which is differentiable everywhere but derivative doesn't keep sign in any one-sided neighbourhood of extremum point.

Comment: @Alann Rosas, I expanded my comment, but why are you worried about extrema? Question is about monotonicity.

Comment: @zkutch Mark clarified in the comments that the question was "*If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable and $f$ has no extrema on $(a,b)$, is $f$ increasing/decreasing?*"

Comment: "clarified" is a strong word. I think this question is still unclear.

Comment: @pancini, I wrote about function with "clarified" property. Is not it?

Comment: @Alann Rosas, I answered last question in body, look at it pls. Answer to your clarifying is in second example of my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^4\left(2+\sin\frac{1}{x} \right), & x\neq 0\\
0, & x=0
\end{cases}$$
function has absolute minimum in $x=0$, but its derivative
$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\left[4x\left(2+\sin\frac{1}{x} \right)-\cos\frac{1}{x}\right], & x\neq 0\\
0, & x=0
\end{cases}$$
doesn't keep sign in any one-sided neighbourhood of zero. Hope, this answers as body of question, so comments.

Additionally let me bring function which has positive derivative in point, but is not monotone in any neighbourhood of point:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x+2x^2\sin\frac{1}{x} , & x\neq 0\\
0, & x=0
\end{cases}$$
with derivative
$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}1+4x\sin\frac{1}{x}-2 \cos\frac{1}{x}, & x\neq 0\\
1, & x=0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this answer is good for your example above, meaning 'there is function which is differentiable everywhere but derivative doesn't keep sign in any one-sided neighborhood of extremum point.' I think you are considering it to have a minimum only at the point like zero. Then if you fix a neighborhood then it is true that the function is non-monotonic, and consider a neighborhood of the point other than zero then it will have a extrema (eg points $x=k \pi$).

Comment: Thanks for estimation. You can mark it as answer, if you find it useful.